# Determining free time between calendar entries

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a system where customers can engage the services of suppliers for a set duration of time.

**The process**
The customer will list a time frame for when they are available (Start DateTime and end Datetime).

The supplier has a calendar where they will have marked the times frames that they are unavailable. This can mean that there will be multiple calendar entries for the day.  Calendar entries are in a table with Start DateTime and End Datetime.

**What i need**
When the customer submits their available times, I need the system to get a list of all the calendar entries for the supplier. and determine if between all their entries there is time for the set duration of time listed above.

**Example**
Customer has supplied the available times 
12/12/2016 7:00am - 12/12/2016 7:00pm

The supplier has the following calendar entries
12/12/2016 8:00am - 12/12/2016 9:00pm
12/12/2016 12:00pm - 12/12/2016 2:00pm
12/12/2016 5:00pm - 12/12/2016 7:00pm

I only need to know if there is at least 2 hours free in the suppliers calendar.  I don't need to know when.  I'm using MVC 5 and Linq queries

**EDIT**
Added the following code.  This currently only tests to see if there is a "packageTime" gap between the customer available Start time and a supplier calendar entry start time then if that same "packageTime" gap exists between calendar entry and time and the customer available endtime.  Id doesn't take into account multiple calendar entries and if there is free time in between those. I can't work out the logic to achieve this.

```
List<Calendar> calendar = db.Calendar.Where(m => m.PhotographersId ==   item.PhotographersId && m.StartTime.Date == bookings.AvailableDate1Start.Date).OrderBy(m => m.StartTime).ToList();

bool date1Free = false;

foreach (var calendarItem in calendar)
{
   DateTime calendarPackageStart, calendarPackageEnd;
   calendarPackageStart = calendarItem.StartTime.AddHours(packageTime * -1);
   calendarPackageEnd = calendarItem.EndTime.AddHours(packageTime);

   if (calendarItem.StartTime.Date == bookings.AvailableDate1Start.Date && !date1Free)
   {
       if (bookings.AvailableDate1Start <= calendarPackageStart)
       {
           date1Free = true;
       }
       else if (bookings.AvailableDate1End >= calendarPackageEnd)
       {
           date1Free = true;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Your example is a little confusing sir, based from your example, what result(s) then do you desire?

Comment: Sorry about that.  I have edited the code to take out some of the bloat and that wasn't specific to the problem  and updated the edit section to explain exactly what i am after

Comment: @Andrew Maybe this will help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ysw4sby(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Andrew why you need to check if there are at least two hours left? Is 2 hours a parameter or a fixed time?

Comment: I don't seem to appreciate this but lets keep going. There's a set clock by the customer (customer availability), and a set clock(S) by the supplier(time differences between available hours). What I find confusing is the priority, are you looking to get if the supplier is available to the customer specified time? or are you looking if the customer has any supplier to see between its available clock? or both? or none?

Comment: @kenlacoste.  I just need to see if the supplier has (x hrs) free between the times supplied by the customer.  I have prob been confusing things by writing too much and overthinking it. sorry for the confusion

Comment: I get it, x hrs = sum of free hours? or just the identified hours? say for your example, the customer is between 7 - 7 (12 hours), then base on your sample if my assumption is correct, your suppliers' free hours in SUM of the customer's availability is 1 hour because the 8 AM to 9 PM is blocked so only available window between customer and supplier is 7 am to 8 AM. isn't it?

Comment: X = the sum of hours the supplier is required to have free between the hours supplied by the customer.  In the example gave. Assume that x hours required to be free is 2 hours. That would mean that the supplier would have enough free time between 9-12 and and then 2-5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the link for date subtract that @Yoda supplied i was able to come to the following solution.  This loops through all the dates on the suppliers calendar and and checks to see if there is (x) hrs free between the dates supplied by the customer.

```
bool isFree = false;
List<Calendar> calendarItems = calendar.Where(m => m.Id == Supplier.Id && m.StartTime.Date == customerAvailableStart.Date).OrderBy(m => m.StartTime).ToList();
if (calendarItems .Count > 0)
{
    DateTime date1, date2;
    date1 = customerAvailableStart;

    for (var i = 0; i <= calendarItems .Count; i++)
    {
        if (i != calendarItems .Count)
        {
            date2 = calendarItems [i].StartTime;
        }
        else
        {
            date2 = customerAvailableEnd;
        }

        if (date2.Subtract(date1).TotalHours >= packageTime)
        {
            isFree = true;
            break;
        }
        date1 = calendarItems [i].EndTime;
    }
}
```